# Automatically disconnection on all port, including ssh and directadmin port

Tags: server, openssh

New to Ubuntu server for home, just start using it for a week and more.

The server is connectable by ssh and port 2222 (directadmin port) after the system startup (power on/reboot) but after the server stays active for a longer period, the server is automatically unable to connect. SSH and directadmin from remote desktop, even I had ping to the IP from a remote desktop to the server. A `ping <IP>` will show this:

```
Reply from 192.168.xx.xx: Destination host unreachable
```

But strangely, if I ping from server -> remote desktop, the connection is back. It just works as if the server is rebooted. I use dynamic and private IP, not static and public IP, is it the case? Or is there any configuration I missed? I reckon it will happen again. This is my first question and I wish to fix this issue.

Comment: Please read  https://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-ask and https://askubuntu.com/help/formatting . Take the [tour].

Comment: Just guessing: Sounds, as if some power saving is deactivating the network interface.